Coherence Resonance in Coupled Chaotic Oscillators
For a project I have to reproduce the results of this papers numerical analysis, specifically those power diagrams. I have written python code attempting to solve this numerical system but I have not yet been able to reproduce those power graphs.
Mathematically, I need to numerically solve a system of coupled Lorenz oscillators, with added white noise in the background and then extract their differences in the y component for 3 different powers of the background white noise, which are marked with D in my code. This is based on the principle of Coherent resonance happening due to the addition of white noise to these coupled oscillators. The first result would be the 3 graphs of $\Delta y(t)$, for each noise level, the second result should be using a Fourier transform on the aforementioned graphs and then getting 3 specific results, showing power dependent on angular frequency, and should look similar as in the following paper.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11955387_Coherence_Resonance_in_Coupled_Chaotic_Oscillators
First oscillator :
\begin{split}
  dx_1 = &  \sigma \cdot (y_1 - x_1) + K \cdot (x_2 - x_1) + \text{noise}_{x_1} \\
    dy_1 = & x_1 \cdot (\rho - z_1) - y_1 + \text{noise}_{y_1} \\ 
    dz_1 =  & x_1 \cdot y_1 - \beta \cdot z_1 + \text{noise}_{z_1}\\
\end{split}
Second oscillator :
\begin{split}
     dx_2 = & \sigma \cdot (y_2 - x_2) + K \cdot (x_1 - x_2) + \text{noise}_{x_2} \\ 
    dy_2 =  & x_2 \cdot (\rho - z_2) - y_2 + \text{noise}_{y_2} \\ 
    dz_2 = &  x_2 \cdot y_2 - \beta \cdot z_2 + \text{noise}_{z_2} \\
\end{split}
Constants:
\begin{split}     
    \rho = & 28.0 \\ 
    \beta =  & 8/3 \\ 
     K = & 4.0 \\ 
    \text{noise_levels} = & [0.001, 0.03, 0.3] \\
    \sigma = & 10.0 \\
\end{split}
I apologise for not defining the problem better before, as I am in a slight panic.
Here is my python code:
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Definiram konstante 

sigma = 10.0 

rho = 28.0 

beta = 8/3 

K = 4.0 #Sklopitveni parameter 

noise_levels = [0.001, 0.03, 0.3] #3je Različni nivoji šuma

#Čas simulacije 

t_span = (0, 10000) 

dt = 0.001 

t_eval = np.arange(t_span[0], t_span[1], dt)

#Začetni pogogji (vse sem dal na 1 ker niso opisani v projektu) 

initial_state = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

#Dva oscilatorja Lorentzovega sistema, kjer uporabim kar np.random.normal za šum, tako je metoda rahlo preprostejša, šum pa se mi zdi ustezen 

def lorenz_system(t, state): 

    
    x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 = state 
    
    noise_x = D * np.random.randn() 
    
    noise_y = D * np.random.randn() 
    
    noise_z = D * np.random.randn()
    
    dx1 = sigma * (y1 - x1) + K * (x2 - x1) + noise_x
    
    dy1 = x1 * (rho - z1) - y1 + noise_y
    
    dz1 = x1 * y1 - beta * z1 + noise_z
    
    dx2 = sigma * (y2 - x2) + K * (x1 - x2) + noise_x
    
    dy2 = x2 * (rho - z2) - y2 + noise_y
    
    dz2 = x2 * y2 - beta * z2 + noise_z
    
    return [dx1, dy1, dz1, dx2, dy2, dz2]
    
#Razrešitev sistema enačb z integriranjem, kjer tudi ven poberemo razlike v y, kot je omenjeno v članku 
    
for D in noise_levels: 
    
    sol = solve_ivp(lorenz_system, t_span, initial_state, t_eval=t_eval, method='RK45') 
    
    y1, y2 = sol.y[1], sol.y[4] 
    
    delta_y = y1 - y2
    
    """#Preračun z furierovo analizo
    
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(delta_y), dt)
    
    power_spectrum = np.abs(np.fft.fft(delta_y))**2"""
    
    #Delta y(t)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
    
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    
    plt.plot(sol.t, delta_y, color='blue')
    
    plt.title(f'Delta y(t) za D={D}')
    
    plt.xlabel('Čas t')
    
    plt.ylabel('Delta y(t)')
    
    plt.grid(True)
    
    """#Izris
    
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    
    plt.plot(2 * np.pi * freqs[freqs > 0], power_spectrum[freqs > 0])
    
    plt.title(f'Furierov spekter moči za Δy(t) ter D={D}')
    
    plt.xlabel('Krožna frekvenca ω')
    
    plt.ylabel('Moč P(ω)')
    
    plt.xlim(0)
    
    plt.ylim(0)
    
    plt.grid(True)
    
plt.tight_layout()
    
plt.savefig(f'plot_D_{D}.png', dpi=1000)
    
plt.show()



It does not find the linked question for me if I try to open link.

The standard solvers do react badly to non-smooth ODE functions. The scipy library does not have dedicated SDE solvers. You would also need to interpret the noise terms, which are mathematically singular, in some SDE fashion, usually Ito or Stratanovich.

I was given these specific methods to solve this problem and I've been made aware that it is possible to do it this way, over my extensive and rigorous testing of my program I have debugged a good part of it  (I am 90% sure it's correct) and come to the conclusion that changing the initial conditions greatly affect the end results. I do not know how to go about finding the correct initial conditions to reproduce the results in the system as there is a lot of possible varriation.
